# I was transferring 2 ETH from Gemini to Exodus, it end up in Etherscan ?? Help!

Tags: transaction-propagation

On 9/18/2019 12:53am, I made a transfer of 2 Eth from Gemini to Exodus, it did not go through, bet end up in Etherscan. 
How did that happened? 
and How to transfer Eth out out Etherscan?
Thanks to all of you smart people. Please help!

Comment: "end up in Etherscan"? "transfer Eth out out Etherscan"? You've got it all wrong, my friend. Etherscan is just a view of the Ethereum blockchain. Nothing can be transfered in or out of there!

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash we can examine?

Answer (score 1):

taken from the web ->
Etherscan is the leading BlockExplorer for the Ethereum Blockchain. A BlockExplorer is basically a search engine that allows users to easily lookup, confirm and validate transactions that have taken place on the Ethereum Blockchain.

https://intercom.help/cent/en/articles/2613353-what-is-etherscan

**Thus, you have not sent your Ether to Etherscan, but to another Ethereum address. Etherscan just shows you from where to where it is sent.**